# Need help converting ASP.Net Module date to js.

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to convert some data to js so I can use ko arrays. This is how I am doing it in the .cshtml file.

`var List = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Item)));`

All of the data is correct except for the date.
When I display it from `Model.Item.Date` is comes out to `3/9/2018`

But when I display it from `List.Date` it gives me this weird string `/Date(1520582400000)/`

What format is this in and how can I convert it?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is milliseconds and you can convert it to a date like this :

```js
var t = new Date().getTime('1520582400000');
var d = new Date(t);
console.log(d.toString());
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Do you know of a better way to pass the date in from c# to js so I wouldn't need to write this extra code to replace the all of the dates? If not its cool, thanks again.

Comment: I don't think so but I will look around.